# How to output taxonomy terms used for WP post?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently working on a project in wordpress where I have a custom taxonomy created for a list of services applied to that individual post.

```
<main id="main" role="main" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
     $services_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sc_project',
     );
     $services_query = new WP_Query( $services_args );
     if ( $services_query->have_posts() ):

     $terms = get_terms( array(
         'taxonomy' => 'sc_project_service',
         'hide_empty' => false,
     ) );
?>  
<section>
  <div>
       <a href="#">Back to Projects</a>
       <h2><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h2>
       <div>
           <div>Services</div>
           <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) :  ?>
              <span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
           <?php endforeach; ?> 
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
</main>
```

So my question is, with this block of code I have the ability to output every single taxonomy term used but how do I go about limiting the output to only the ones for that specific post?

Any input would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) instead of `get_terms()`:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'sc_project_service' );
```

Comment: @Buckk Not a problem (: